# Role privileges in Wicket DropDownChoice

Tags: wicket, roles, behavior, user-permissions

In my project I have a few forms, mostly `DropDownChoices` like **City**, **Budget Type**, **Financing Source** and etc. And in the project I have user roles like **ROLE08**, **ROLE27** and **ROLE51**. And depending to the user **ROLE**, the data in my `DropDownChoices` is changing. For example, if **ROLE08** could see all city regions, the **ROLE27** and **ROLE51** just can see two or three city regions. How I can implement that issue architecturally right?

I can't mind up, how to create user behaviours, user rules for the project, and user access levels. I think I need create my own custom `DropDownChoices` where I can declare my custom Model data, and ChoiceRender rules. Could anyone additionally draw me a scheme, how it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at Wicket [IAuthorizationStrategy](https://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/authorization/IAuthorizationStrategy.html)  Interface.